# Tikz and vim-latex compile garbage

Tags: tikz-pgf, vim-latex

I'm new to vim-latex and to tikz. I'm trying to create a FSM using **tikz** library as explained [here](http://sebastian-doerner.de/?p=249). I used the same lated code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,fit}
\begin{document}
%hello world!
%in the document
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(pseudo) at (-1,0){};
\node(0) at (0,0)[shape=circle,draw]        {$q_0$};
\node(1) at (2,0)[shape=circle,draw]        {$q_1$};
\node(2) at (4,0)[shape=circle,draw]        {$q_2$};
\node(3) at (6,0)[shape=circle,draw,double] {$q_f$};
\path [->]
  (0)      edge                 node [above]  {b}     (1)
  (1)      edge                 node [above]  {a}     (2)
  (2)      edge                 node [above]  {b}     (3)
  (2)      edge [bend left=30]  node [below]  {a}     (0)
  (0)      edge [loop above]    node [above]  {a}     ()
  (1)      edge [loop above]    node [above]  {b}     ()
  (3)      edge [loop above]    node [above]  {a,b}   ()
  (pseudo) edge                                       (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I paste this code in Texmaker, it generates the right FSM as described in the link above. But when I paste it in vim (vim-latex installed following [this](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download)), it just generate a pdf file that has some letters over each other in the middle of the page. 
Could someone please tell me what is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try setting `let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'` which will call `pdflatex`.  By default vim-LaTeX uses the `dvi->ps->pdf` chain rather than `pdflatex` which I think has caused trouble with TikZ in past questions.

Comment: See if my answer to [Vim Latex ''compacts'' Tikz pictures during compile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353537/106162) helps, this may be a dupe.

Comment: Thank @DaiBowen, it works now fine for me after adding `let g: ..` to .vimrc.

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: No need to delete it, if it's marked as a duplicate then that may make it easier for others to find the solution (different questions appear in different searches) and is sufficient for the question to be treated as resolved. Nothing should stop you deleting the question if you really want to.

Comment: Then I'll not delete it. 
Thanks again for your quick replies